# excel vba issues creating a chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to add some code to the bottom of an already working macro that will add a chart to the sheet that i just copied data into. the amount of data is changing regularly so I need the data range to be variable. however when I run the code it gives me the error "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

```
Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name Search")
Dim rng As range
Dim cht As Object
lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Your data range for the chart
  Set rng = destSheet.range("F6:G" & lMaxRows)

'Create a chart
  Set cht = destSheet.Shapes.AddChart2

'Give chart some data
  cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Determine the chart type
  cht.chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
```

the error is occuring on the line under the "Your data range for the chart" note. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ive never been able to successfully make a chart through VBA before

Comment: `Dim rng As range` - did you copy this directly from the VB editor? `range` should be automatically converted to `Range`: if that's not happeneing then there is something off in your code (did you define a variable named "range" somewhere ?)

Comment: yes, i wrote it in VBE following a guide i found online

Comment: "yes" to which question?

Comment: i coppied it directly from the editor and defined rng in the first set statement and used it in the stement above the last comment

Comment: Check the rest of your code for a variable or sub/function called "range" - something is wrong there.

Comment: i have this code isolated in a separate sub untill i get it running and it gives me that error

Comment: Copy just that code into a new workbook and compile it.  Is "range" automatically converted to "Range" ?

Comment: What is the value of `lMaxRows`? Could you check it in the debugger or print it out before the statement?

Comment: @Vbasic4now can you also upload the rest of your relevant code ?

Comment: Sometimes the VB Editor will stop capitalizing a certain type, who knows why. I'm more interested in how `lMaxRows` is declared (should be a Long) and what its value is.